Trying to create a trigger, that will print out error upon creating too many rows
But got stuck at PRINT: for some reason i get an error that says that my message is invalid and it expects an identifier after PRINT. What am I doing wrong?
CREATE TRIGGER insert_check
AFTER INSERT
ON country
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (country_id > 195) THEN
        PRINT 'All countries already exist'
    END IF
END;


You seem to be missing a few semicolons... every statement in MySQL needs to be terminated with one.

And a quick search of the MySQL docs shows that there is no PRINT statement,

What can use instead of print then, i saw someone use it, and it worked for them for some reason (i guess they used different type of sql or something like that). And if i add more semicolons i just get more errors

Use your favourite search engine... people have been discussing this for years.

And don't just randomly add semi-colons - add them where rerquired.

If i add one after ' ' or after end if i get errors. I tried to find something that i can get a message out, but nothing seems to work unfortunately. Plus its almost 5 am so my head doesn't work as well as i would like to

You need to consult the documentation.

I guess so, ill go read it. But any other ideas are still welcome too

Thats for the semi-colons, duck-duck-go "print in mysql" for your actual question.

Why would you want to print something anyway? Your application can't use that. Throw an exception.

Trying to create a trigger, that will print out error upon creating too many rows Impossible. The trigger code cannot put anything to the output stream. What can use instead of print then, i saw someone use it, and it worked for them for some reason (i guess they used different type of sql or something like that). You may fail/break the whole INSERT query if your condition succeed with SIGNAL statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/79267544/10138734 as a sample.

PRINT is a sqlserver statement not available in mysql.. If you are learning sql (of which there are many dialects which are incompatible in many ways) be sure to install the dialect used in the teaching material.
